# Learning jQuery and getJSON but having issues

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I am trying to learn jQuery (getJSON right now) and am having a hard time.  I've searched over and over again, and cannot seem to figure out why this isn't working.

The JSON:

```
            {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "type" : "upload",
                    "who" : "chris ",
                    "action" : "uploaded a wallpaper entitled: ",
                    "target" : "Blah blah blah",
                    "time" : "3 hours ago"
            }
```

Here is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function() {
        $.getJSON("/js/activity.json", function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                console.log(key + " : " + value);
            });
        });
    });
})
```

and of course the HTML is just a simple

```
<button>Test</button>
```

Why is this not outputting anything to the console? if i put an alert right after the `.getJSON` it doesn't fire but if I put one before it do

Comment: Did you try using the complete URL in the getJSON call? Also, you're probably missing a semicolon at the end.

Comment: Origin ADDRESS is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. is what i get when i use a full URL (i am doing this on my own live site right now)

Comment: Basically: Make sure you're using the correct paths, `'/js/activity.json'` redirects to the DocumentRoot of your webserver, not relative to the file you're using your JS in. If you want it relative, remove the / at the beginning, eg `'js/activity.json'`.

Comment: "js/activity.json" gives the same results (I am running this at the root of the drive so /js/activity.json is the same as js/activity.json)

Comment: Also, if you're using Chrome, the developer console (Ctrl+Shift+J by default) allows you to log the requests, just right-click in the window and enable "Log XMLHttpRequests". Same might be true for FireBug, don't know for sure though.

Comment: Do you have any links to your test page so we can take a look at it in complete?

Comment: www.chrisworrell.com/test.html

Comment: anyways yea it is successfully loading the XHR

Comment: Remove the comments on your activity.json file.

Comment: hah simple enough, stupid me didnt realize you couldnt comment in json files THANKS!

Comment: You also have a comma at the end of the last element.  That will work in newer browsers, but could cause issues in older ones like IE6 or 7.

Answer (score 1):

Your activity.json file contains comments, remove them. Comments are not part of the JSON specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few things.  In the callback function (the one in the getJSON call), just put a console.log("test"); to see if you are getting in the callback.  You can also watch the JSON call in the .Net panel of Firebug or the Network panel of the Chrome Inspector to make sure it is firing and returning your file correctly.  It might be that your server doesn't know how to return JSON files correctly, for example.

If it is working correctly (i.e. path is correct, file is being read) then just try logging data - console.log(data) and make sure that it is showing your JSON.  Then you can worry about looping through the keys, you don't need that step to see that it is working correctly.